How to Remove 'Select All' Option in SSRS While Allowing Multiple Values?
I'm working on an SSRS report where I need to allow users to select multiple values for a parameter. However, I want to hide the default "Select All" option that appears when "Allow multiple values" is enabled.
Here's what I've done so far:
1) Parameter Setup:
Parameter Name: ORG_NAME
Data Type: Text
Allow multiple values: Checked
Available Values: Populated from a dataset query (does not include "Select All")
2) Dataset Query:
    SELECT DISTINCT ORGANIZATION_CODE, ORGANIZATION_NAME
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE ORGANIZATION_NAME <> 'Select All'
    ORDER BY ORGANIZATION_NAME

3) Additional Boolean Parameter:
Parameter Name: SelectAll
Data Type: Boolean
Default Value: False
Prompt: Select All
4) Custom Code in Report Properties:
    Public Function RemoveSelectAll(ByVal items As Object()) As Object()
        Dim newItems As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object)
        For Each item As Object In items
            If item <> "Select All" Then
                newItems.Add(item)
            End If
        Next
        Return newItems.ToArray()
    End Function


Expression to Handle Parameter Values:

=IIf(Parameters!SelectAll.Value, "All Organizations Selected", Join(Parameters!ORG_NAME.Label, ", "))

Despite these steps, the "Select All" checkbox still appears in the parameter dropdown.
My Goal:
I want to hide the "Select All" option in the parameter dropdown while still allowing users to select multiple values.
Questions:
Is there a way to programmatically remove or hide the "Select All" option in SSRS while keeping the "Allow multiple values" functionality?
Are there any alternative approaches or best practices to achieve this functionality in SSRS?
Environment:
SSRS Report Builder
SQL Server 2016
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

I think you might be complicating this more that it needs to be.  why do you even need a "Select All" when allowing multiple values. Simply selecting all the Multiple values inthe drop down list implies select all!

@harry op is asking exactly how they can remove select all, because they don't want it!

Afaik it's not possible to remove the select all option.

Why do you want to remove "Select All"? People will still be able to select all in a more arduous way by doing it manually. A long time since I used SSRS so I can't remember if this applies there but in general I find "Select All" useful even when I have no intention of Selecting All (as often toggling this on and off will clear all previously selected selections)

Pretty sure there isn't as well. Smells like an XY Problem to me. What are you really trying to achieve here?

As a side note, SQL Server 2012 reached en off life over 2 years ago; you really need to get that upgrade plan you finalised back in 2021 implemented.
